# Google Fit exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to read data for session which was not returned

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I'm getting an exception and have no idea what it means.

Here is my code:

```
Session session = new Session.Builder()
                .setActivity(healthType.plainType)
                .setStartTime(thirtyDaysAgoCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
        SessionsClient client = Fitness.getSessionsClient(context, googleSignInAccount);
        client.readSession(readRequest).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<SessionReadResponse>() {
            List<DataSet> dataSets = sessionReadResponse.getDataSet(session);
        }
```

This is the full exception message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to read data for session Session{startTime=1629493522319, endTime=0, name=null, identifier=1629493522319, description=, activity=4, application=null} which was not returned

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this:

```
    SessionsClient client = Fitness.getSessionsClient(context, googleSignInAccount);
    client.readSession(readRequest).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<SessionReadResponse>() {
        ArrayList<DataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
                for(Session session : sessionReadResponse.getSessions()){
                    List<DataSet> set = sessionReadResponse.getDataSet(session);
                    for(DataSet dataSet : set){
                        dataSets.add(dataSet);
                    }
                }
    }
```